# REGEXP MySQL - several Groups no matter which order

Tags: mysql, regex, sorting

i try to create a REGEX in MySQL but after 4 hours of reading other examples and try & error i hope someone can help me to fix my regex and bring it to work.

What i need is:
to match several strings in a seperatet("###") text no matter in which position/order they are inside "###***TEXT***###***TEXT***###"

My regex so far which work, but only if the strings in the exact order like in the regex. So i have to say my regex search STRING1 && STRING2 inside ### ### no matter in which position.

```
###([^#]*)(9034==1-wellig)([^#]*)(9037==DIN C4)([^#]*)###
```

My Text:

```
###9021==220|9034==1-wellig|9023==356|9024==230|9037==DIN C4###9021==220|9034==2-wellig|9023==356|9037==DIN C4|9024==230###9021==220|9034==1-wellig|9023==356|9037==DIN C4|9024==230###
```

When i modify my Text to something like that("9037==DIN C4" before "9034==1-wellig") it do not work:

```
###9021==220|9037==DIN C4|9034==1-wellig|9023==356|9024==230###9021==220|9034==2-wellig|9023==356|9037==DIN C4|9024==230###9021==220|9037==DIN C4|9034==1-wellig|9023==356|9024==230###
```

Example: https://regex101.com/r/amal7c/1

I hope i explained my problem clearly, im sure it´s only 1 small change but i do not get it to work...

Best Regards
Tom

Comment: What is your target environment? If you write a regex for PHP/PCRE, and run in MySQL, it might not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use lookarounds in MySQL regex, you need to use alternations:

```
WHERE col REGEXP '###[^#]*(9034==1-wellig[^#]*9037==DIN C4|9037==DIN C4[^#]*9034==1-wellig)[^#]*###'
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/DBjn3m/2).

**Details**

- `###` - literal `###`
- `[^#]*` - zero or more chars other than `#`
- `(9034==1-wellig[^#]*9037==DIN C4|9037==DIN C4[^#]*9034==1-wellig)` -
  an alternation capturing group matching

  - `9034==1-wellig[^#]*9037==DIN C4` - `9034==1-wellig`, zero or more chars other than `#` and `9037==DIN C4`
  - `|` - or
  - `9037==DIN C4[^#]*9034==1-wellig` - `9037==DIN C4`, zero or more chars other than `#` and `9034==1-wellig`
- `[^#]*###` - zero or more chars other than `#` followed with `###`.

Answer (score 0):

OMG ok i think i just found the solution by myself, it working on regex101 but not in MySQL :/

```
###(?=[^#]*(9034==1-wellig))(?=[^#]*(9037==DIN C4))[^#]*###
```

But if some of you experts can enhance my regex im also very thankfull :)

https://regex101.com/r/amal7c/2

Comment: ty @wiktor this will work, but the STRINGS im searching are dynamic that meas it can be also 3 or up to 10. Is there any other way for searching  ### STRING1 STRING2 STRING3 STRING4 ### no matter in which order ?

Comment: ok i think my regex will work now ty@wiktor. It will be a big regex maybe there is a more elegant way but this work and performance seems also not so poor :).

Example with 3 STRINGS: https://regex101.com/r/DBjn3m/3

Comment: Good, I posted my answer.